# Pyspark independent word counts for many files

Tags: python, apache-spark, word-count

I am trying to find word frequencies across multiple files, ultimately returning a list with lists of word frequency tuples for each files.

Eg:

> [[File1 word frequencies],[File2 word frequencies,...[FileN word
>   frequences]]

.

I am actually just pulling words from a subset of lines for each file. This code works:

```
titles = sc.textFile(text_file) \
.glom() \
.map(lambda x: " ".join(x)) \
.flatMap(lambda x: x.split("PMID- ")) \
.map(lambda x: x[x.find('TI ')+5:]) \
.map(lambda x: x[:(x.find('  - ')-3)]) \
.map(lambda x: x.replace('.','').replace(',','').replace('?','').replace('-',' ').replace('   ',' ').replace('   ',' ').lower())

title_word_freq = titles.flatMap(lambda x: x.split()) \
.map(lambda x: (x,1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y) \
.map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])) \
.sortByKey(ascending=False)
```

As expected, this returns a list of word frequencies for the file `text_file` or for all of the *.txt files in the directory specified by text_file.

What I would to do, however is to run this independently on each file in a directory. I have tried a few things, such as:

```
t_files = sc.wholeTextFiles("PATH")
indiv_files = t_files.map(lambda x: x[1])
word_counts = indiv_files.map(getWordCounts)
```

Where `getWordCounts` is a function defined as the preview code block modified in various ways (such as removing the .glom()). I have been unable to get this to work unless I include a transformation that combines all of the files, which defeats the purpose.

Any suggestions?